# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DeletedDatabaseRecord',...; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: acumatica

I get this error when checking my added field and saving

"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DeletedDatabaseRecord', table '...'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

the statement has been terminated"

here is my create statement for my extension table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RQRequestTableExtension]
(
    [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderNbr] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BranchID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DeletedDatabaseRecord] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AdminApproval] [Bit],
    CONSTRAINT [RQRequestTableExtension_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
    [CompanyID] ASC,
    [OrderNbr] ASC,
    [BranchID] ASC

)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF,
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RQRequestTableExtension] ADD DEFAULT ((0))
FOR [DeletedDatabaseRecord]
GO
```

Here is my DAC extension

```
namespace PurchaseRequisitionApproveButton
{
    [PXTable(typeof(RQRequest.orderNbr), typeof(RQRequest.branchID),
IsOptional = true)]
    public class RQRequestTableExtension : PXCacheExtension<RQRequest>
    {
        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Admin Approval", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        public bool? AdminApproval { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong PXTable attributes.  Here is how I declared mine (not using Optional).  You don't need BranchID

```
    [PXTable(typeof(RQRequest.orderNbr))]
    public class RQRequestExtension : PXCacheExtension<RQRequest>
```

Also you don't need to add DeletedDatabaseRecord field.  It is not included in the original table.